# How to keep the content script injected in a tab even if user navigates to another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension in which I have *popup.js*, *background.js* and *myscript.js* (content script). Whenever I click on the extension icon, through browserAction it launches a new window which is of type panel. Then, when I click on the 'Record' button in my panel window, *popup.js* passes a message to *background.js*:

***popup.js*:**

```js
$("#rcrd_btnr").click(function(ee)
{
    alert('about to start recoding');

    //send message from popup.js to background.js
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({from : 'record'});

    'rcrd_btn_blue' is a button to stop the recording of events on page //
    $("#rcrd_btn_red").hide();
    $("#rcrd_btn_blue").show();
});
```

Further, *background.js* passes a message to *myscript.js* (content script),

***background.js*:**

```js
if(request.from === 'record')
{
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({ tabId : actvTabId,color: "green" });
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({tabId : actvTabId,text: 'R'});
    chrome.tabs.query({active:true}, function(tabs)
    {
        for(var i=0;i<tabs.length;i++)
        {
            if(tabs[i].selected == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    //send to active tab to myscript from backgrund_record
                    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[i].id, {
                        from : 'btn_record',
                        win_id:windo.id
                    }, function(response) {});
                }
                catch(e)
                {
                    alert('sending failed');
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Then, in *myscript.js*, I have two events:

```js
$( "body" ).click(function( event ){...});
```

and

```js
$("input").change(function(eventChange){...});
```

These events capture any 'clicks' and 'types by user' on the active tab and send them back to *background.js* and further to the *popup.js*:

***myscript.js* (content script):**

```js
if(message.from === 'btn_record')
{
    $( "body" ).click(function( event ) 
    {
        try
        {
            //find element being clicked 
            var ele = document.getElementsByTagName(event.target.nodeName);

            //sending message back to background.js
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({from : 'btn_record_myscript',msg : 'clicked'});
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            alert(e);
        }
    });

    //change event for 'input type=text'
    $("input").change(function(eventChange)
    {
        var ele = document.getElementsByTagName(eventChange.target.nodeName);
        //sending message back to background.js 
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({from : 'btn_record_myscript',  msg :'typed'});
    });
}
```

**Problem :**
Whenever I click the 'record' button, it successfully captures both events on the active tab (the tab from which I had my last focus). But, when I click on any hyperlink on the page, then the page navigates to another page on the same tab. I am then not able to detect any of the events on the new page, even though they are in the same tab.

How can I re-inject the content script or keep it injected? I am stuck at this stage really bad.

**I am ready to provide any further info, if needed.**

**######UPDATE######**

**$$$$$   USE JQUERY FILE ALSO   $$$$$**

[All Files Gist](https://gist.github.com/p10shinde/6bc791dd2e11638b25b8da36ba4649cc)

**popup.js**

```
var rcrd_btn_cntr=0;
      $(document).ready(function()    {

            //listen mssage from record_button_red
            $("#rcrd_btnr").click(function(ee)
            {
                //alert('about to start recoding');

                //send message from record_to_background
                chrome.runtime.sendMessage({from : 'record'});
                // console.log(ws);
                $("#rcrd_btnr").hide();
                $("#rcrd_btnb").show();
            });

            //listen mssage from record_button_blue
            $("#rcrd_btnb").click(function(ee)
            {
                alert('about to stop recoding');
                $("#rcrd_btnb").hide();
                $("#rcrd_btnr").show();
                //send messagee from record_Button_stop
                chrome.runtime.sendMessage({from : 'cancel'});
            });


    //Listens for message coming from background
            chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (answer)
            {
            if(answer.from === 'b_r_m_background')
                {
                    if(typeof(answer) != 'undefined')
                    {
                        var row = '<tr><td>'+answer.command+'<td>'+answer.target+'<td>'+answer.value;
                        $('#mytbl').append(row);
                        console.log(answer.msg)
                        //alert(answer.msg);
                    }
                 }
            });


   });
```

**background.js**

```
//create new window of type panel
var run =0;
var win_id;
var ifClosed=1;
var vid=0;
var xx ;
var actvTabId;


    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) 
    {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) { 
    actvTabId = tab.id
    });



        chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(win)
        {
            xx = win;
            if(run==0 && ifClosed ==1)
            {
                chrome.windows.create({ type:"panel",url: "index.html","width" : 400,"height" : 600}, function(win) 
                {
                    win_id = win.id;
                //  alert('creating '+win_id);
                    run++;
                    ifClosed=0;
                });
            }
            else if(ifClosed == 0)
            {
                //alert('updating '+win_id);
                chrome.windows.update(win_id, {focused: true});
            }

        });
    }); 


        //listen for a message coming from panel_window
        chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) 
        {

            if(request.from == 'cancel')
            {

                //sending to active tab (myscript) from back 

                    //console.log('sending to myscript from back_cancel');
                    //console.log(sender);
                    chrome.tabs.query({active:true}, function(tabs)
                    {
                        for(var i=0;i<tabs.length;i++)
                        {
                            if(tabs[i].selected == true)
                            {
                                //chrome.tabs.update(tabs[i].id, {selected: true});
                                //send to active tab to myscript from back_cancel_button
                                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[i].id, {from : 'btn2_2_cancel'}, function(response) {});
                            }
                        }
                    });
                //console.log('sent from back.js');



            }
            //listen incoming from panel_window_record_button
            else if(request.from === 'record')
            {

                chrome.tabs.query({active:true}, function(tabs)
                {
                    for(var i=0;i<tabs.length;i++)
                    {
                        if(tabs[i].selected == true)
                        {
                            //chrome.tabs.update(tabs[i].id, {selected: true});
                            //sending to active tab (myscript) from back 
                            try
                            {
                            //send to active tab to myscript from backgrund_record
                            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[i].id, {from : 'btn_record',win_id:xx.id}, function(response) {});
                            }
                            catch(e)
                            {
                                alert('record background send failed');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            //listen incoming from active tab from myscript for logging events
            else if ( request.from =='btn_record_myscript' )
            {
                //send to panel window from background for logging events
                chrome.runtime.sendMessage({from:'b_r_m_background',msg : request.msg});
            }

        });


//when panel_window is closed
        chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function (event)
        {

        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({tabId : actvTabId,text: ''});
            ifClosed = 1;
            run=0;  
            //alert(ifClosed);
            //alert('window is closed');
            chrome.tabs.query({active:true}, function(tabs)
            {
                for(var i=0;i<tabs.length;i++)
                {
                    if(tabs[i].selected == true)
                    {
                    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[i].id, {from : 'btn2_2_cancel'}, function(response) {});
                    }
                break;
                }
            });
        });
```

**myScript.js**

```
var cntr=0;
var cbtr2=0;
var typed = '';
var tp='null';
var isFirstTime=0;

        $(document).ready(function()    
        {
            //listen for incoming from background
            chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (message,sender, sendResponse)
            {

                //listen incoming from cancel_button_background_panel_window
                if(message.from === 'btn2_2_cancel')
                {
                    //console.log('cencelling');
                    //in case of 'panel window close' or 'cancel button click' unbind all events from page
                    $('body').unbind('mouseover');
                    $('body').unbind('mouseout');
                    $('body').unbind('click');
                    $('body').unbind('keydown');

                }

                else if(message.from === 'btn_record')
                {

                    current_loc = window.location.href;
                    $( "body" ).click(function( event ) 
                    {                   

                            //find element being clicked 
                            var ele = document.getElementsByTagName(event.target.nodeName);
                        //  alert('sending from click');

                            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({from : 'btn_record_myscript',msg : ele[0]});

                    });

                    //change event for 'input type=text'
                    var key_detect;
                    $("input").change(function(eventChange)
                    {
                    var ele = document.getElementsByTagName(eventChange.target.nodeName);

                        //key detect event  
                        $("body").keydown(function (eventKey)
                        {
                            key_detect = eventKey.key;
                        });
                        //check if user has pressed enter 
                        if(key_detect == 13 || eventChange.type == 'change')
                        {               
                            typed = eventChange.target.value;
                        //  alert('sending from type');
                            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({from : 'btn_record_myscript', msg : ele});
                        }
                    });

                }
                else
                {
                alert('error');
                }


            });
////////onMessage Listener ends///////////      
                });
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src = "popup.js"></script>

  <meta charset="utf-8">


  <title>My AddOn</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css"/>
</head>
<body >

<div>
<input type="button" value="Re" id ="rcrd_btnr" name="record"  style="position:absolute;left:40%;text-align: center;background-color : red ;text-decoration: bold;font-size: 10px;padding:10px 10px;border: none;color: white;cursor: pointer;border-radius:100%"/> 
<input type="button" value="Re" id ="rcrd_btnb" name="record"  hidden style="position:relative;left:40%;text-align: center;background-color : blue ;text-decoration: bold;font-size: 10px;padding:10px 10px;border: none;color: white;cursor: pointer;border-radius:100%"/> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "TestExtension",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description" : "Test Descr.",
    "icons": { "48": "bear.png"},

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": { "16": "bear.png", "32": "bear.png" },
        "default_title": "Test Addon"
    },
    "permissions": ["tabs"],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "js": ["jquery.js","popup.js","myScript.js"]
    }]
}
```

Comment: A content script is a like an additional script of the page (even though it runs in separate environment) so it can't outlive the page itself when it's destroyed upon navigation to a different page. You'll have to keep track of url navigations in your background page script using e.g. chrome.tabs.onUpdated. I believe there are many examples of that on StackOverflow so good luck finding them. Or maybe someone will post a custom-tailored answer here.

Comment: ok thanks...will give it a shot...and will let you know..

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Usually, including a *manifest.json*, some of the background *and* content scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: To be specific: You do not show how or why the content script is injected into the page. You are asking us to show you how to "keep the content script injected". Even though doing so is impossible (see wOxxOm's comment), how are we supposed to make suggestions such that from a functional standpoint you get something close when you don't show how the content script is injected in the first place

Comment: in your content script, why do you have `var ele = document.getElementsByTagName(event.target.nodeName);`? Your comment says that it is to get the element being clicked. However, you already have that element as `event.target`. It makes no sense to use `event.target.nodeName` to get a list of nodes from which you want to find the one that is `event.target`. Even if it did make sense to do so, you never use the `ele` variable, so there is no need for it to exist.

Comment: Actually i have removed some part of code. That 'ele' is being passed to another function for processing. I will put all code and manifest too.

Comment: What you don't show with your code so far is how the content script is injected in the first place.

Comment: I have updated it. All files are included. Just try and make chrome addon in developer mode. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem. What I have done is, I have a listener to check if clicked object is hyperlink in my **myscript.js** and **chrome.onUpdated** API in **background.js** . Whenever user clicks on hyperlink a message is send to **chrome.onUpdated** API in **background.js** In which I have used **setTimeout** which again injects **myscript.js**.